foreign key vs hasMany() in models Laravel
the user has many tasks, id add a foreign key in tasks table refer to user , if i want to delete user i want to delete all the tasks for this user , i do this in controller
task::where('user_id',$user_id)->delete();
user::where('id',$user_id)->delete();


but there is another way that says
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}

and in controller :
$user = User::find($id);
$user->tasks()->delete();
$user->delete();


is one of this ways better than the other in performance ???
what is better???????????

Please provide the generated SQL.

Test both options out with larger scale of test data and you will know which performs better in your case. To decide which of the two is better, you need to define a clear criyeria for ranking both solutions. But if you have clear tanking, then you can test against those criteria

Obviously the first option is "faster" since the second option first retrieves the user and then applies the same queries. However, the difference is not going to be noticeable at all, and i personally always use the second one for legibility.

For better performance, use onDeleteCascade which allows the database to do it automatically. You can add this in your migration file. When it is done like this just delete the user and his tasks will be automatically deleted
In migration of tasks
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();


i know this practice but i add "delete method" as example , thanks for answer
